# REST API getById using Integer or String?

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I'm designing a REST JAX-RS API with Jersey.

I want to know what is the best practice to get an object by ID.
Do I need to map the ID on an `Integer` or a `String`

**Solution 1:**

```
/books/{id}
getById(@PathParam("id") Long id)
```

**Solution 2:**

```
/books/{id}
getById(@PathParam("id") String id)
```

My intention was to used `Long` because it is directly mapped on my database model using a `Long`...

Answer (score 1):

If you need a `long`, make the parameter a `long`.

If JAX-RS can't map a path parameter requested by the client to `long`, it will return a `404 Not Found` HTTP status code which is a good thing. If you allow `String`, your code will have to do this check. Let JAX-RS do the checking.

```
@GET
@Path("/books/{id}")
public Response getBook(@PathParam("id") long id) {
    return Response.ok("book " + id).build();
}
```

A request for `/books/123` will return `book 123`. A request for `/books/foo` will fail with `404 Not Found`.